# How to identify letters in an image using Python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to use OpenCV to identify the letters of an image.

So far I'm reading the image > Applying Blur > Identifying the Edges of the letters, but for some of them it works well, but most of them I'm facing 2 kind of problems:

1. Sometimes the cv2.Canny() cannot identify all the letters, or just part of them (like the example below it is missing the last letter "d" and it is taking just part of the letter "m")
2. Some letters have a shadow below them and it is has been identifying as a edge and coming below the letter.

Original Image:

[image]

Processed image:

[image]

Code:

```
img = cv2.imread('.\\new_letters\\image.jpg', 0)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(5,5),0)
edges = cv2.Canny(blur,20,60)
```

Please I would like to ask if you have any idea on how can I identify all the letter properly and how can I remove the lines created by the shadow of some letters?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: You could try **Difference of Gaussians**

Answer (score 3):

As stated I tried using **DoG**  **(Difference of Gaussians)**. But before that I enhanced the image using **histogram equalization**.

```
equalized_image = cv2.equalizeHist(gray_img)
cv2.imwrite('Equalized Image.jpg', equalized_image)
```

This is the histogram equalized image:

[image]

I then performed DoG on this:

```
imgb1 = cv2.GaussianBlur(equalized_image, (11, 11), 0)
imgb2 = cv2.GaussianBlur(equalized_image, (31, 31), 0)
diff = imgb1 - imgb2
cv2.imwrite('diff.jpg',diff)
```

The result:

[image]

It does not look good, but given the quality of your image this the maximum you can get. Had it been a better image the result would have been better.

*Note:* Difference of Gaussians is basically another form of an edge detector.